# A UTF32 value should not include surrogate codepoint values

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

I'm having trouble with this kind of errors after I try to add the image for the background

> A valid UTF32 value is between 0x000000 and 0x10ffff, inclusive, and should not include surrogate codepoint values (0x00d800 ~ 0x00dfff)A valid UTF32 value is between 0x000000 and 0x10ffff, inclusive, and should not include surrogate codepoint values (0x00d800 ~ 0x00dfff)

the error appear on this coding:

_Layout.cshtml

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

This is the coding for background image:

Site.css

```
background-image: url('Image\672d0ab79a9c2655e6d3155c7760580e.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin:auto;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=A+valid+UTF32+value+is+between+surrogate+site:stackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Very unlikely the code you posted gives you such an error. Please right-click and choose inspect and look at the console error - to the far right is the link to the place that generates the error

Comment: thank you! actually this my first time on programming and stack overflow

Comment: No problem That is why I posted the links to the help center